# Prove that set is not precompact in $l_p$

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the set $M_{\alpha,\beta}$ in $l_p$, where $1 \leq p < \infty$:
$$M_{\alpha, \beta} = \{x \in l_p:  \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n^{\alpha} |x_{n}^{\beta}| \leq 1   \}$$

This set is precompact for the values of the parameter $\beta \in (0, p], \alpha > 0$ and $\beta > p, \alpha > \frac{\beta}{p}-1$

I want to prove that for another values of parameters set $M_{\alpha,\beta}$ is not precompact. To prove that I tried to use $l_p$'s precompactness criterion, which says a set is precompact if it's bounded and the following condition is true: $$\forall \epsilon > 0  \quad \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: (\sum\limits_{j=N}^\infty |x_{j}^{p}|)^{\frac{1}{p}} < \epsilon \quad\forall x \in M$$

However, I didn't succeed to prove that. Can anyone help me? Thank you

Comment: Please show what you have done so far.

Comment: @geetha290krm I probably have nothing to show, because I tried to apply the negation of the criterion above, but almost immediately got into a stupor, not understanding how to show that the set is unlimited or the second condition of the criterion is not met, that’s why I’m asking for help